# PHP :Initializing elements of session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, initialization

I have created a session array  as

```
$_SESSION[yans]=array();
```

I wish to initialize first 5 elements of this to 0.How it can be done?

Comment: Can't understand your question..

Comment: `$_SESSION[yans]=[0,0,0,0,0];`

Comment: `$_SESSION["yans"] = array_fill(0, 5, 0);` I don't see where your problem is?!

Comment: and change [yans] to ['yans']

Comment: It looks like your entire question has changed drastically. You really should have posted a new question as now all the answers and comments make no sense and have no relation to your question.

Comment: @KevinNagurski This is my end result. What I had asked earlier was an intermediate step.But I guess i will posting a new question about the same

Comment: @SudarshanTaparia Please don't edit your post fully like that. Your new question was completely different and it invalidated all of the answers. I've rolled back the change.  In the future, post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every on suggested above, try this:-

```
<?php
session_start();


$_SESSION['yans'] = array('A','B','C','D','E');
echo "<pre/>";print_r($_SESSION);die;

?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/7btkxv

Note:- it's a simple example given for your understanding. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_fill` function to achieve this:

```
$_SESSION['yans'] = array_fill(0, 5, 0);
```

You should also remember to quote the `yans`, otherwise PHP will raise a `NOTICE` (unless `yans` is actually a defined constant).